# unix - prepend file contents of file to all *.html files

Tags: unix, prepend

Anyone know how to do the following through the command line?

- i have X number of html files
- i would like to prepend the contents of file2.txt to all these html files

the result would be

- each file would have the content of file2.txt prepended in front.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, you can

```
prefix=$(cat file2.txt)
for file in *.html; do
  html=$(cat $file)
  echo "$prefix$html" > $file
done
```

#### Edit

Alternatively, use a temp file:

```
for file in *.html; do
  temp=$(mktemp /tmp/html.XXXXXX)
  cat file2.txt > $temp
  cat $file >> $temp
  mv $temp $file
done
```

Comment: Not sure that storing file contents in variables is a good idea.

Comment: Me neither, but there was no constraint put in the question!

Comment: To me both are valid, but the need dictates the one I'd use. For scripts I'd prefer the latter; for a one-time fix on the command line, probably the former.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vi commands in the editor `ed`. You can append a file using `r file`, but you need it before the first line. The `ed` command is `0 r file`. Write and quit in combination with a here-construction will give:

```
for f in *.html; do
    ed -s "${f}" <<EOF
0 r file2.txt
w
q
EOF

done
```